# Taking elements from second array, minus invalid values

Tags: c#

I have the following arrays:

```
int[] masterProducts = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];
int[] selectedProducts = [1, 2, 3, 8];
```

I want to create an array that only has the `selectedProducts`, minus any invalid products (ex. from above, `8` is an invalid product because it is not in `masterProducts`).

So I have 2 questions:

1. What is the simplest code to find out that `selectedProducts` has an invalid product? I could do some for/looping but that seems inefficient.
2. What is the simplest way in C# to take only `selectedProducts`, minus any invalid products (minus the number `8` in this case)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> What is the simplest code to find out that selectedProducts has an
>   invalid product? I could do some for/looping but that seems
>   inefficient.

It's easy to do with LINQ [`Except`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779(v=vs.110).aspx) method which produces the set difference of two sequences. Note that performance also will be pretty good, because it's a set operation (uses hash set internally):

```
bool hasInvalidProduct = selectedProducts.Except(masterProducts).Any();
```

> What is the simplest way in C# to take only selectedProducts, minus
>   any invalid products (minus the number 8 in this case)?

It's also easy one - you can use [Intersect](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb460136(v=vs.110).aspx) operator which produces the set intersection of two sequences:

```
var validProducts = selectedProducts.Intersect(masterProducts);
```

This a set operator too, and it also uses hash set internally to quickly find if the item from the first sequence exists in the hash set created from the second sequence items - O(1) operation.

Comment: @Targaryen `Except`, `Any` and `Intersect` are extension methods from `System.Linq` namespace. All these methods are extensions for any enumerable data type - both list of integers and array are fine. Make sure you have appropriate `using` at the top of file